# How can I pass my referrer from current page to iframe without using php?

Tags: javascript, nginx, http-headers, http-referer, referer

I have an iframe in mysite.com/folder/file.php

The iframe is an html page from a subdomain and I want to block all referers except the current page it's embeded in (mysite.com/folder/file.php)

What's the best approach to this, using javascript ?

I tried to define rules in Nginx but the problem is the headers always show subdomain.com as the referer instead of showing current page.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx approach could work. There is an nginx module which can filter by referer.

But the docs for that module state that the header is unreliable. It can be easily modified to show incorrect information by hackers.

But the DOM in the iframe'd html page should give you access to the 'parent' object.

That object could then be used to obtain information from the parent page like url or even some custom data you could set in  the parent page.

I am not a javascript expert but I think this is the better approach.